# Discrepancy in content experiment sessions

Tags: session, google-analytics, google-experiments, content-experiments

I noticed a huge discrepancy in the count of sessions for one of our experiments in Google Analytics.

The API says 3,123 sessions for variation 0 and 3,039 for variation 1. 
[GA API screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qG0N.png)

At the same time the report in google.com/analytics reads 5,743 for variation 0 and 5,620 for variation 1. [GA Web screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlEQF.png)

The above data is: 

 - on the exact same dates

 - with no filters

 - with no segments

 - on the same Google Analytics view id

Could you please help me figure this out?

Thanks, 
V.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that ga_sessions in query explorer (api) is not the same as experiment sessions in content experiments interface.

Read this for more information on experiment conversion rate and sessions calculation:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6112437#

Here is a quotation:

> Conversion rate is calculated using the same methodology as Analytics:
>   total converted visits divided by total visits (once a user becomes a
>   part of an experiment). A user is considered part of an experiment
>   once he or she has seen the experiment page. For example, if a user
>   sees the experiment page, then comes back the next day, the second
>   visit is counted, even if the user does not view the experiment page
>   again.

Comment: Hey Yury, thanks for taking the time to share insights on the differences in the counting methodology employed by Content Experiment reports and the rest of Google Analytics. This might explain smaller discrepancies but in my case it doesn't seem to be the root of the problem...

Comment: Actually, for me ir seems to be the root of the problem. I've made a research regarding the Google experiment sessions nature using big query. The difference between GA_sessions on experiment page and experiment sessions in Google analytics ui is because if calculation methodology. Experiment session here is any session of any user who have already visited experiment page. Even sessions when user did not visit experiment page are summarised.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the previous point Yury! There is no question it's factor. In my case I'm skeptical about it simply because I am talking about a website with very simple structure where the content never changes:

Comment: 1. Landing page
2. Join offer
3. Checkout
Also due to the nature of the website (used for SEM) we don't have a lot of returning visitors. With this being said I don't see where any repeat sessions would come from...

Comment: What is the amount of returning visitors for your website during the experiment period?  Is it more or less than 20%?

Comment: Before the experiment we had 16.9% returning visitors. 
During the experiment we have 17.5%. Does this help?

Comment: The thing here is that GA sessions in API and GA experiment sessions are calculated differently.
Sessions in API - it is a number of all sessions when the user visited experiment page during it
Experimental Sessions - takes into account all user sessions (both including and not exp page) starting from the first session that included experimental page

So the results seem normal for me